Give an approximation of $f(x)$ given that $m\leq f'(x)-g'(x)\leq M$
Given 2 real differentiable functions on $(a,b)$ $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, give an approximation of $f(x)$ given that $m\leq f'(x)-g'(x)\leq M$ for some real numbers $m, M$ and $a>0$. Also, $g(x)$ is known for every $x\in [a,b]$. My try: define the differentiable function on $(a,b)$ $E(x)=f(x)-g(x)$ from here we know that  $m\leq E'(x)\leq M$ so and by the mean value theorem $m\leq \frac{E(x)-E(a)}{x-a}\leq M$ so $m(x-a)+E(a)\leq E(x)\leq M(x-a)+E(a)$ or rewriting $m(x-a)+E(a)-g(x)\leq f(x)\leq M(x-a)+E(a)-g(x)$.
Is there a better approximation?

You seem to need to know $E(a)$.  Since you do know $g(a)=f(a)-E(a)$ from the question, this implies you need to know $f(a)$ but it is not obvious to me that you do.  Knowing $f((a+b)/2)$ could give you a tighter approximation.
